# large message Sender.Forward 133KB

Tags: c#, akka.net

I am trying to send a txt file (size 133 kB)

```
public class HelloActor : UntypedActor
{
    public HelloActor()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnReceive(object request)
    {
        var data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+"myfile.txt");
        Sender.Forward(data);
    }
}
```

and this is my client code

```
var actor = System.ActorSelection("HelloActor");
return await actor.Ask<string>(null, TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
```

This is not working.

Comment: "is not working" isn't a description that anyone can work with. When a mechanic asks you what's wrong with your car, do you think "is not working" is enough?

Comment: I mean Akka did not give any response to what I send from server to client, but i have already set maximum-frame-size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue has nothing to do with maximum-frame-size, as probably your actor behavior haven't been called at all. Assuming that you have created your actor using system's `ActorOf` and named it *HelloActor*, two things in your code are invalid:

1. It's not allowed to send `null` as message. Specify some specific value instead. This error is actually printed in error log.
2. Your actor selection uses invalid path. For top level actor in user space it would be `/user/HelloActor`. You'd find it in the logs as message will not reach the recipient and be pushed into dead letters instead. You can read more about actor paths [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/addressing.html).